# SDL: Window freezes

Tags: c++, sdl, freeze

I wanted to start working on SDL. I got a sample code to see if it worked fine. When compiling I get no errors, but when I run it the window shows up but the program freezes until the delay time is over.
I'm new to this so I would really appreciate some help.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

SDL_Window *window = 0;

window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        640, 480,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

SDL_Delay(10000);

SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You're missing an event loop. Your tutorial should cover that.

Comment: Please add a link to explain what is SDL. ( https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init )

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati I don't see why we need a link. There's already a tag, which explains what SDL is.

Comment: @underscore_d this is just my own opinion. If you make the word SDL a link, it will avoid confusion with MFC / SDL / MDL (https://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/VisualC.html) but since there is a tag, it isn't mandatory.

Comment: _"I got a sample code"_ Did you actually get this from some tutorial? Or did you mean you wrote it up yourself? Because if the problem is what people have said, the tutorial shouldn't be giving this out as sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @HolyBlackCat, you need an event loop : 
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent

It should look something like this :

```
while (true) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        /* handle your event here */
    }
    /* do some other stuff here -- draw your app, etc. */
}
```

**Edit**
You will need to replace your delay with the event loop.
Instead, you can close the application on an event. The least you can/should do, is handle the [SDL_QUIT](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EventType#Remarks) event, which is sent when the user try to close the window:

```
while (!quit) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        /* handle your event here */

       //User requests quit
        if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            quit = true;
    }
    /* do some other stuff here -- draw your app, etc. */
}
```